# TypeError: returnVentana() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

for some reason I have an error like the one in the title.
In my game I try to show the letter "a" on the screen, which is a drawing of the images folder.

Previously I managed to fix the error including () behind "ventana" on line 119 but still the drawing was not showing on the screen and the program seemed to be going quite slow. Does anyone know how to fix it? Next I leave the code and the link to GitHub.

https://github.com/jordispir/AlphaJuego

```
#__main__.py

import pygame
import pruebaVentana

pygame.init()
ventana = pruebaVentana.Ventana()
juego = pruebaVentana.Juego()

while not ventana.eventoSalir():
    ventana.empiezaFrame()
    juego.eventosTeclas()
    juego.dibuja()
    ventana.acabarFrame()

#pruebaventana.py

import pygame
import os

def obtenPath(directorio):
    pathFicheroScript = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    directorioTrabajo = os.path.dirname(pathFicheroScript)
    pathRecurso = os.path.join(directorioTrabajo, directorio)

    return pathRecurso

def obtenPathDeRecurso(directorio, elemento):
    path = obtenPath(directorio)
    return os.path.join(path, elemento)

rutaFondoPantalla = obtenPathDeRecurso("pantallas", "fondoPantalla.png")
fondoPantalla = pygame.image.load(rutaFondoPantalla)

rutaPantallaLogin = obtenPathDeRecurso("pantallas", "pantallaLogin.jpg")
pantallaLogin = pygame.image.load(rutaPantallaLogin)

rutaLetra_a = obtenPathDeRecurso("imagenes", "letra_a.png")
letra_a = pygame.image.load(rutaLetra_a)

rutaPuntosEscritura = obtenPathDeRecurso("imagenes", "puntosEscritura.png")
puntosEscritura = pygame.image.load(rutaPuntosEscritura)

class Ventana():
    def __init__(self):
        #self.width, self.height = 300, 500
        self.ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 500))
        self.reloj = pygame.time.Clock()
        pygame.display.set_caption("AlphaGame")
        pygame.display.flip()

    def returnVentana(self):
        return self.ventana

    def eventoSalir(self):
        out = False
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            out = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                out = True

        return out

    def empiezaFrame(self):
        self.ventana.blit(pantallaLogin, (0, 0) )

    def acabarFrame(self):
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.reloj.tick(60)

class Juego:

    def eventosTeclas(self):
        self.teclaPresionada_a = False 
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                self.teclaPresionada_a = True
            else:
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.teclaPresionada_a = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_b:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_g:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_h:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_i:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_j:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_k:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_l:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_m:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_n:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_o:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_t:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_v:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_y:
                pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_z:
                pass

    def dibuja(self):
        if self.teclaPresionada_a == True:
            Ventana.returnVentana().blit( (letra_a), (50, 325) ) #(x, y)
            print("teclaPresionada == True")
```

Now, I have tried to change something in the class juego and it seems to work, but anyway, the screen gets black.

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.teclaPresionada_a = False

    def eventosTeclas(self):
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                self.teclaPresionada_a = True
            else:
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.teclaPresionada_a = False
                    print ("teclaPresionada = False")

def dibuja(self):
        if self.teclaPresionada_a == True:
            Ventana().returnVentana().blit( (letra_a), (50, 325) ) #(x, y)
            print("teclaPresionada == True")
```

Comment: `returnVentana` is an instance method rather than a class method. You need an instance of the class `Ventana` to invoke `returnVentana`. Read about [Method Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects)  and [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects). Where do you create an instance object of  `Ventana`? somewhere in your code you have to do something like  `my_ventana = Ventana()`

Comment: Ok, now I'm seeing a black screen.